# SQL - How do I retrieve the count of unique entires which correspond to non-unique entries?

Tags: sql

I need to pull the count of the "Skill" column for each unique "FileID."

For example, my table looks like:

[image: Table Example]

So I would like the output in this scenario to be:

400100 - 4

400200 - 3

400300 - 3

I am still relatively new to SQL so hopefully what I am asking is clear.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use group by and aggregate function

```
select fieldid, count(skill)
from tablename
group by fieldid
```

Comment: Certainly, will do - once the time limit passes I'll mark as such :)